# Mysql one to one vs null vs json

Tags: mysql, json, database

I am designing a system that stores information about certain orders, that have multiple optional attributes, and I am wondering what's the best way of storing information in the database.

I saw this kind of question asked many times but, not specific answer, so here goes:

I have table of orders which have many optional parameters, and I am wondering what design would give me the best practice and best performance:

So far I came up with 3 solutions of this problem:

First and the simplest would be to ignore fact of optional parameters, and store "NULL" values, when no entry is needed here's how the outcome might look:

```
Table:
|Id|Column1|Column2|Column3|Column4|Column5|Column6|Column7|Column8|Column9|Column10|
|1 | Data  | NULL  | Data  | Data  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | Data  | Data  | Data   |
|2 | Data  | Data  | Data  | NULL  | Data  | Data  | NULL  | Data  | NULL  | Data   |
|3 | Data  | NULL  | NULL  | Data  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | Data  | NULL  | Data   |
|4 | Data  | NULL  | Data  | Data  | NULL  | Data  | NULL  | NULL  | Data  | Data   |
```

And so on... This example is simple and you can see where I am going with this (so many NULL values inside table).

Second solution is to have meta data table with one to many relation which would store parameters if they exist (something like wordpress stored meta data of posts?), for example how it could look (This is example of first 2 rows of table above):

```
MainTable:
|Id|Column1|Column10|
|1 | Data  |  Data  |
|2 | Data  |  Data  |

MetaDataTable:
|Id|MainTId|AttrKey|AttrValue|
|1 |   1   |Column3|   Data  |
|2 |   1   |Column4|   Data  |
|3 |   1   |Column8|   Data  |
|4 |   1   |Column9|   Data  |
|5 |   2   |Column2|   Data  |
|6 |   2   |Column3|   Data  |
|7 |   2   |Column5|   Data  |
|8 |   2   |Column6|   Data  |
|9 |   2   |Column8|   Data  |
```

And so on... This drops NULL values completely but the problem I see with this design is that table size grows exponentially witch each new record, and I think that later the performance of querying such table would kill me mentally, but maybe that could be no problem if I use joins?.

The third solution is to have optional data serialized into JSON string and then saved inside database, kinda like mongodb?. This is how it would look:

```
Table: 
|Id|Column1|Column10|                         AttrData                                |
|1 | Data  |  Data  |"{"Column2":null,"Column3":"Data","Column4":"Data","Column5":....|
|2 | Data  |  Data  |"{"Column2":"Data","Column3":"Data","Column4":null,"Column5":....|
```

The rest of the logic how to display data would be left to php.

So which solution would be combination of best practices and performance, or maybe there's other methods, that I could not think about out. Note that I left one to one attribute table solution not mentioned as I think querying each parameter from different table would kill the performance, since I would have so many tables.

Comment: The second approach is also known as EAV (Entity Attribute Value) modelling, but I don't think it really applies here; that said, it's likely that some of those columns can be grouped together (i.e. 2NF), so you may need to introduce multiple tables.

Comment: I've answered the best I could, but you ask for a very specific answer without giving us much specific details. Can we have a bit of detail on the data stored? Also, are there gonna be lots of updates or non at all? How many "optional parameters" do you expect at first? Is there be a need for strong, advanced filtering options when looking at the list? ...

Answer (score 0):

Actually it depends on how volatile the parameters themselves are which you try to store and how many distinct values you need.

In case of many parameters which tend to alter often and many parameters need to be added later on, I tend to go for the JSON solution: Its easier to maintain, since adding a parameter does not need a database change, as well as deleting one. Maintenance of consistency of the JSON structure may be encapsulated in to a particular object with getters and setters as well.

If there are only few distinct parameters which may stay stable for the next 42 years, a relational (normalized) structure like #2 is the best from my perspective.

Answer (score 0):

A little missing info to get a very focused answer is how are you gonna need to retrieve the data afterwards...

Since it is orders, I assume you'd want all the info available when looking at one. But are you gonna only order them by date? Or will you require some filters on the data, like to handle shipments by country, or order type?

Your first solution seems to be the most straight forward, **easiest to handle** and won't require huge MySQL skills to do complicated queries, as you will only juggle with one table. Some of the problems I can foresee is if you have thousand of possible parameters, having a thousand rows would seem overkill if only a dozen is filled on a normal order. But if most of the fields are filled, it's gonna be fine. You will also be able to **benefit from typing your columns**. If a new column is needed, on a big table the process can take a long time and the table will be **locked for writes during that process**.

Your second solution is one that I like using when having a lot of volatile info. When I do not know in advance what is the name of the data and the data itself. Taking as example a MySQL table that logs fatal errors and dumps all the variables of the current scope. This is very helpful, but might get a **bit slower** when needed to search your orders according to the data saved in those. The worst to note about that, is that you **will not be able to type the column** according to the data, as it will store anything.

Your third solution is going to give you some problems later on. Let's imagine you want to search on a criteria, a hard regexp will be needed and may return false positives. **You will need to use PHP or other scripting language** if you need to do an UPDATE on a row. Some info like the date of the order should be put in different column so you can at least use it to order.

With all that said, I would go with the first solution, using a single big table. This will make **your life easier on your queries**, and server. But if there is too much data columns needed and most of them will not always be filled, opt for **a mix of option one and two**. Keep all the fields that will be needed (read vital) for the order on the order table, and use an extra table to put your extras like in your second solution. That way you mix the strong points of both solutions.

Comment: Ok, more information: The data stores should be read only, and once written it should be set to stone, never to be updated, and about read vital information, every parameter if it exists should be read and displayed for user, so we could say that every parameter is vital, but I see your point in atm I actually have 2nd solution realized as you say by opting both of best, because there a static attributed that are there all the time, as such I store them in main table, and all others (optional) I store in another table.

Comment: But I am expecting hundreds of thousand records inside table because of design of system (orders are generated by other system, and most of time they are not used, never the less, I still need to store information about them), so in single day I can expect 200~ new order records, and I am afraid that after some time, querying 2nd table would be pain, since it could contain millions of records since each new record can add 10-15 new rows to 2nd tabble

Comment: If you set your indexes accordingly, having your second table won't cause performence problem when displaying the data. It will only cause a bit of degradation if you are to use one of its column in a WHERE statetement for filtering. SELECTing on text columns is a lot slower than int for example, and in your second solution, since we give one type for all data, you will certainly need to use TEXT and this will force a TEMPORARY table copy on every SELECT. But that would also happen if you select a text column anyway...